windows server DHCP multiple scope relay trouble
I want to create 14 subnets (10.10.10.0/23, 10.10.20.0/23, 10.10.30.0/23, etc)
I have a DHCP server running on a 15. subnet, 10.100.10.0/24 with the address of 10.100.10.100.
The problem that arises is that when I create more than 1 scope in the DHCP-server, the leases start moving from the DHCP-server table, and into the router DHCP lease table. I can also see that the leases provided have DNS from the router, and not the windowsserver.
Does anyone have any idea what this "fault" is?
-I have configured all interfaces except "the 15. subnet" with relay agent on the router pointing to DHCP-server address. Switches are also configured with IP-helper address that point to the DHCP-server.
there are no other DHCP service activated in the network, or any networks except for the windowsserver.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I have checked on client that DHCP and DNS "server" is listed as Gateway. this I find very strange as all interfaces except the one with DHCP-server is on is enabled as Relay agent only.

show us how your network is working, having 2 dhcp in the same network is not possible without seperation in any kind

Does anyone have any idea what this "fault" is? - Yes. You have 2 DHCP servers. Turn off the DHCP server on the router.

But I already have... I have a teltonika router that you set DHCP to either disabled, Relay, or Enabled on each interface. I have disabled DHCP on DHCP-server network, and added Relay on the interfaces for the other networks.
Only interface DHCP is active is in WAN network (I dont have a static public address on the router)

I have finally isolated the error. everything works great aslong as I only have one interface on the router activated with relay. the second I change interface configuration on another subnet to relay instead of disabled, I get assigned DHCP configuration from the router and not the winserver.
if I disable all the scopes on the winserver, I get no ip configuration on any subnets.

The fault was caused by missing IP-helper address on the "core" switch. (I had to setup interface based relay, vlan based was apparently not enough). works as intended now.
